# How to sync one or two labels only, from Gmail to Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail

As many are facing the problem of IMAP syncing all the mails of Gmail, I want to know how can one sync specific Gmail labels to Mail.app?

For example, if I have Friends, Family, Company1, Company2, and Bank labels, how can I only synchronize Friends and Family?

Also, It should not apply that setting uniformly to all my syncs.
For example, I want to sync all my mails to my Nexus 5, but only few labels with Mail.app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the labels shown in your IMAP client in Google Mail settings via the checkbox on the right side.

[image: GMail settings]

Comment: I have updated my question following your answer.

Comment: This would still sync all emails, just won't show these labels as folders.